# Areas and routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3-areas

I'm quite stuck I might say dispite all other posts found on the site.

My solution has two areas Front and Back, and I don't want to use the default root controllers and views provided by default.

My **FrontAreaRegistration.cs** is like :

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
    context.MapRoute(
        "Front",
        "Front/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        , new[] { "Show.Areas.Front.Controllers" }
    );
}
```

My **BackAreaRegistration.cs** is like :

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
    context.MapRoute(
        "Back_default",
        "Back/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Account", action = "LogOn", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        , new[] { "Show.Areas.Back.Controllers" }
    );
}
```

And **Global.asax** like :

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

Getting folowing exception :

> Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'Home'. This
>   can happen if the route that services this request
>   ('{controller}/{action}/{id}') does not specify namespaces to search
>   for a controller that matches the request. If this is the case,
>   register this route by calling an overload of the 'MapRoute' method
>   that takes a 'namespaces' parameter.
>
> The request for 'Home' has found the following matching controllers:
>   Show.Areas.Front.Controllers.HomeController
>   Show.Areas.Back.Controllers.HomeController

Problem is I can't reach the Home controller from Front area. Even if correct namespace added to context.MapRoute method overload ...

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What url do you type into browser?

Comment: None, just launch with F5, it should hit the default controller "Home" and action "Index" ? Though, when I type http://localhost:xxxxx/Front/Home/Index in adress bar it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is raised because you don't specify Area name in your request. Because of that "Default" route (from Global.asax) is matched for request and tries to search "Index" action of "Home" controller. As far as there two matches (for both areas) exceptions is thrown.

There are few ways to fix this. One possible is to modify Global.asax:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   "Default", // Route name
   "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
   new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter defaults
   new[] { "Show.Areas.Front.Controllers" }
).DataTokens.Add("Area", "Front");
```

But in this case "Default" route will work for Front area only.

Comment: I've tried this one but following exception is thrown :

The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Home/Index.aspx
~/Views/Home/Index.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Index.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Index.ascx
~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Home/Index.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.vbhtml

(Great if Front is the default area)

Comment: Yipee, your answer just made my day ! Thanks a lot petro.